# Create and make analysis CortexDB

Tags: database, nosql, key-value-store

I expose my problem: I have recently started using CortexDB, a NoSQL software to database analysis. I have read the (poor) documentation on https://docs.cortex-ag.com/en/CortexDB/CortexDB/, and purchased a free license to evaluate the operation of the program. As the documentation is unclear I would have some questions to ask you:

1) How do I create a database?

2) how can I import a database contained in an excel file (.csv)?

3) how do I create charts or analyzes regarding the data entered?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because the question is very old I hope I can still help you.

First of all: you should download the latest release of the free version (simple registration and download)

1. if you downloaded the free version you got the server and two databases. A server process handles one database. For a second database you have to start a second server (different port of course). If you start the free version you should have an empty database (or the filled and configured demo db). If you want to create a complete new one without any predefined configuration, you have to start the server process with the command line and the parameter -n (ctxserver64 -n). If you did that you have to configure everything by hand with the tool ‘remote admin’.
2. the question is not clear for me. Do you mean how to import a csv file into a CortexDB or do you mean how to import the database content into an excel file?

   If you want to import the csv file into a CortxDB, the easiest way is to use the tool CortexImplex. It’s completely explained in the online docs (https://docs.cortex-ag.com/en/CortexImplex/CortexImplex-Basics/)

   If you want to export datasets as csv file the only thing you have to do is to configure a list in the CortexUniplex as a view for your datasets and export them as csv (you find the export function in the list menu).
3. I would do the charting with d3j. For this you can use the so called ‘DataService’ of the CortexUniplex. It’s a kind of an API for posting requests and getting JSON objects. If you have a completely configured UniPlex you can use all of your configuration as json objects for other apps (for example charts or an individual application).

   The full version has a simple dashboard inside of the CortexUniplex. Maybe the vendor offers it in the free free version.

By the way: it’s always good to write an email to the info address. Because this database is not so famous and known, the guys are very helpful. Or contact them via twitter or other channels (see at the bottom of the cort ex-ag.com webpage).